# Can Blender take two video files and overlay them with transparency?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency, video

Can Blender take two video files and overlay them with transparency?

Essentially I want to have a video sequence playing while a 2nd sequence is overlayed and also playing, but that 2nd sequence is transparent (think alpha transparency) in order to see both both sequences.

This might have the effect of the classic film ghost to it, where you can see through the 'ghost' to the sequence it has been overlayed on.

Is this possible in Blender?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

To overlay a video, simply layer one on top of the other in the VSE timeline.
[image]

To make the top one transparent, simply use the opacity slider in the properties panel. 0 is for fully transparency, and 1 is for full opacity.

[image]

Comment: Why the down vote? Could be useful to know why people don't like it so it can be improved.

Comment: Well, without having downvoted it, I think you should elaborate a bit more, talking about different blend types for example...

Comment: @Polosson Thanks for your input. I added a section on layering (which seemed obvious to me, but I realized it a major part of the question also). I don't think blending modes are really relevant, but thank you for the idea.

Comment: Also note that the VSE uses a nonlinear reference space, which means that all blends will be "incorrect", including the original question regarding a cross. To properly blend two RGB images, the internal reference must be linearized.

Comment: @TroyJamesSobotka Why is this important? The question was simply about layering two videos, with the top one partially transparent. I don't see why an answer has to be very complex when the question isn't complex in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @TARDIS Maker, I'll get to grip with some basics and try out your solution tonight or tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @TARDIS Maker.

Comment: @TARDISMaker, I talked about blending modes because the OP said "Alpha transparency", and my first thought was "Alpha Over" blending mode. However your answer seems to be the right one!